# Looking for image distortion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image, graphics, image-processing

Recently I saw demonstration of image distortion algorithm that preserves some objects in image. For example changing weight/height ratio but preserving people faces in image to look realistically. The problem is i can't find the reference to that demonstration neither I know the name of such transformations.

Can anybody point me to a references to such algorithms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are referring to [liquid rescale](http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/)?

Answer (score 4):

[Seam carving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving) is the current favourite.  [Liquid Rescale](http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/en:examples) is an implementation of it.